# Toggle between two most recent windows of the same app in Mac

Tags: macos, shortcut

We know that using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (Cmd + backtick) will allow you to switch between windows of the same app. Suppose I have 5 windows of Chrome and I want to toggle between two most recent windows of Chrome. Is there a shortcut for that? Can we assign one?

Comment: Add "SHIFT" to that key command. I don't use Chrome but it does work on Safari.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same headache for a long time.

I am using the following app to achieve the behavior:

**Alt-Tab:** [Homepage](https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/) and [Github URL](https://github.com/lwouis/alt-tab-macos)

Comment: Great underrated tip! I can't believe switching back to the most recently used window is not a default shortcut in macos. One of the many annoyances I have had since I switched from windows to mac...