# Command + Tilde the most recent active 2 windows

Tags: keyboard, mac

I am able to switch between windows of the same app with <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> shortcut, however it doesn't behave in the way I am used to. I am coming from Linux Ubuntu. Equivalent <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> shortcut there does the same thing with one important difference. It goes back and forth between the last 2 windows of the app. In contrary, Mac switches windows sequentially (1, 2, 3 and so on).

I often happen to open more than 2 windows of Visual Studio Code and Terminal. That's why it's really important for me to switch between the most recently active 2 windows, not all of them. I know that <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> reverse the switching order, but it is not convenient to press 3 keys every time (let alone keeping in mind the next direction).

How can I achieve the mentioned desired behavior in Mac?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If I type `Cmd-~-~-~-~` it cycles through the windows. Are you letting go of the Cmd key between each tilde?

Comment: Holding Cmd key or not doesn't make a difference for me. Look at this [recording](https://we.tl/t-97pp2e66b9). Browser has 3 different windows: This page, Youtube, Google. ⌘ Command~ switches it like Stack Exchange -> Youtube -> Google -> Stack Exchange -> Youtube and so on. I want it to be like Stack Exchange -> Youtube -> Stack Exchange -> Youtube ...

Comment: Unless there's some 3rd party app that would enable this, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you wanted, I had it backwards. With Cmd-Tab, if you keep holding the Cmd key, it steps through the list of apps, but if you let go it alternates apps. But with Cmd-backtick, it doesn't matter, it cycles through all windows either way.

Comment: I tried looking into this and couldn't find anyway other than using `Shift`+`Cmd`+`Grave-accent (\`)` keyboard shortcut to switch back to the previous window, but that means going back and forward holding and releasing the `Shift` key. You might have better luck with a third party application, in which case you would need to disable "Move focus to next window" keyboard shortcut in `Settings`>`Keyboard`>`Shortcuts`>`Keyboard` so that the third party application keyboard shortcut doesn't conflict with the global keyboard shortcuts. Best of luck

Comment: By the way, the only solution I could find is using third party app. This answer might help... https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395392/toggle-between-two-most-recent-windows-of-the-same-app-in-mac